# Scree Plot for determining K in K Means

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am learning R and while doing K Means clustering, I came across the below function several times for determining the best K from the scree plot.
Now, I do understand the logic behind the function but I am having a tough time understanding the R function, can somebody please explain.

```
wssplot <- function(data, nc=15, seed=1234)
  {
    wss <- (nrow(data)-1)*sum(apply(data,2,var))
    for (i in 2:nc)
    {
      set.seed(seed)
      wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(data, centers=i)$withinss)
    }
    plot(1:nc, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
    ylab="Within groups sum of squares")
}
```

Comment: What you don't understand?

Comment: To avoid edit of the title: [scree plot](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/modeling-statistics/multivariate/principal-components-and-factor-analysis/what-is-a-scree-plot/)

Comment: I don't understand the need and function of `wss <- (nrow(data)-1)*sum(apply(data,2,var))`.

Comment: @Pascal - what should I call it, I couldn't come up with a different title. Please suggest!

Comment: What are you talking about? Keep your title as it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function runs `kmeans` `nc-1` times and finds vector of sum of squares, which it sums up. This is the result of each iteration which are in turn plotted on a graph where on x axis there is number of clusters and y axis shows the sum of sum of squares.

Comment: Thanks @Roman, so what I understand is that it creates a vector of 'within sum of squares' in wss and then plots it against number of clusters from 2 to 15. I don't understand the need and functionality of `wss <- (nrow(data)-1)*sum(apply(data,2,var))`. I removed it from the function and still get the same plot.

Comment: `wss` is a vector of length 1 and is overwritten (and elongated) by the loop. This may be a rudimentary variable from a previous version of the function or something that has stayed in during the writing of the function. Or a very cumbersome way of initializing an object that is needed for the loop to write in. You could replace it with `wss <- rep(NA, length(2:nc))`.